# VHDL - Shifting an array of bytes

Tags: arrays, scroll, byte, vhdl, shift

I'm having some problems with a shifter module that will shift the indexes of an array that is composed of bytes.

shifter.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use work.mypackage2.all; -- contains the type reg array

entity shifter is
    generic ( REGSIZE  : integer := 8);
    port(clk      : in  std_logic;
            Scan_Dav : in  std_logic;
            Data_in  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            Data_out : out reg_array );
end shifter;

architecture bhv of shifter is

    signal shift_reg : reg_array;
begin
    process (clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
                if Scan_Dav = '1' then
                    shift_reg <= shift_reg(shift_reg'high-1 downto 0) & Data_in;
                end if;
          end if;
    end process;
     Data_out <= shift_reg;
end bhv;
```

This is a shifter that will hold the scancodes from the keyboard and the output array will be used to scroll the text on seven segment display. My package holds the type declaration used to define the output of shifter:

mypackage2.vhd:

```
--  Package File Template
--
--  Purpose: This package defines supplemental types, subtypes, 
--       constants, and functions 


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package mypackage2 is

   subtype reg is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- a byte
    type reg_array is array (7 downto 0) of reg; -- array of bytes

end mypackage2;


package body mypackage2 is

end mypackage2;
```

I'm having problems with it though. The RTL schematic of this code appears to be as:

[image: RTL of shifter:]

I'm confused why this happens, can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What tool are you using to generate and view the RTL schematic? In my experience, viewing an RTL schematic is rarely useful, and - perhaps because they are rarely used - they tend to be buggy. I would pay more attention to what your VHDL code did in simulation. Write a testbench and simulate it...

Comment: Looks perfectly allright to me, except for the missing clock, which might be a feature of your schematic tool. The VHDL code looks fine, too. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: The problem is exactly that BennyBarns, the schematic is not consistent with the code. There should be 3 inputs and 1 output, their names should be same with what I assigned in the code, and the width of the logic_vectors should be visible in the schematic. I am using Xilinx ISE @Brian. For instance, when I put this device in a top module it does not behave properly:(http://i.imgur.com/QoOPQ.jpg?1)

See how other components are properly drawn.

Comment: Try an experiment : replace every occurrence of the name "shifter" in your design with "my_shifter". See if "my_shifter" appears in the RTL view (you may need to do some "cleanup project" steps to make this happen). This will at least eliminate the possibility that Xilinx ISE has some intrinsic part with the same name, and different pin names...

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but as I expected that was not the issue. However, I expanded the test you proposed, and changed the module output to see if the algorithm is okay. The problem seems to be related with the package I am using to define reg array, or in other words, the compiler is having a hard time to interpret "array of bytes". Is there any alternative to defining such type that is used as an output?

Comment: I just tried synthesising this entity my_shifter using your packake in ISE Webpack 13.1 and it worked just fine. The RTL viewer shows all the expected ports (though it splits the reg_array up into 8 separate reg ports. So I have to ask - which version of ISE are you using? I'll re-test with ISE14 but it'll be 7 more hours before I have it downloaded...

Answer (score 0):

Your "my_shifter" appears to be fine - in itself. The Xilinx tools compile it successfully and the RTL viewer displays it successfully, custom signals in a pagkage and all.

However, embedding "my_shifter" in a top level design with your 7-segment controller, I managed to reproduce the symptoms of the "error" that puzzled you - it would not display in the RTL view of the top level diagram.

Paying attention to the warnings in the "Synthesis Report" I found some other signals were  not connected, allowing the synthesis tool to optimise away the entire shifter! Confirmed by looking at the number of flipflops generated in the summary

Fix those missed connections, and sure enough the Shifter appears with all its ports properly connected in the RTL view.

So I withdraw my suggestion that the RTL viewer may be buggy (in this respect!) but strengthen my suggestion that it is a very poor way to solve basic design problems.

That is what simulation is for.

Otherwise you are working much harder than necessary, and being mis-led about where the problems are.

Comment: Brian thank you for your concern first of all, but I changed my module completely. Lets continue from my other question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856657/vhdl-scrolling-text-on-7-segment-display)