# VHDL - Scrolling Text on 7 segment Display

Tags: text, scroll, vhdl, shift, segment

I am near to end in my project but stuck at some point. I can not resolve the problem

After deciding VHDL is having a hard time shifting indexes of arrays, I decided to change my shifter module. Now it is properly compiling and the RTL schematic seems true, but unfortunately I used a rather non-innovative way to shift the scancodes.

I defined an 64bit std_logic_vector that can hold up to 8 scancodes, and then parsed the 4 MSBmost bytes of this vector, and directed them to seven segment controller, that muxes the inputs and decides which seven segment will be enabled. I am thinking that I have problems with clock, but seeing nothing on the display makes me think some part of the device is malfunctioning. I am sure my keyboard controller works fine, as I tried it outindividually, shifter looks fine as well( I also tried this one on FPGA but without slowing the clock down, but nevertheless I was able to see the last scancode I entered), I haven't thought of any way/method to try out 7 segment controller, but that seems fine too. I don't know what the problem is, the text is not scrolling :(

[image: Top Module]

Shifter.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity my_shifter is
        port(clk      : in  std_logic;
                Scan_Dav : in  std_logic;
                Data_in  : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
                O1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                O2 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                O3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                O4 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                );
end my_shifter;

architecture bhv of my_shifter is

signal bytes : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin
    process (clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
                if Scan_Dav = '1' then
                    bytes <= bytes (bytes'high-8 downto 0) & Data_in;
                end if;
          end if;
    end process;
     O1 <= bytes(63 downto 56);
     O2 <= bytes(55 downto 48);
     O3 <= bytes(47 downto 40);
     O4 <= bytes(39 downto 32);
end bhv;
```

clkdivide.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity clkdivide is
    Port (clkin: in std_logic;
            clkout:out std_logic );
end clkdivide;

architecture Behavioral of clkdivide is
    signal int_clock:std_logic;
    begin
        clkout<=int_clock;
    process(clkin)
        variable var:integer range 0 to 12500 :=0;
        begin
            if (clkin'event and clkin = '1') then
                if var = 12500 then
                    int_clock <= not int_clock; 
                    var:=0;
                else 
                    var:=var+1;
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

SevenSegmentControl.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

entity SevenSegmentController is
    port (
        CLK: in std_logic;
        DEC1, DEC2, DEC3, DEC4: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        SEGMENTS: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        ANODES: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end SevenSegmentController;

architecture Behavioral of SevenSegmentController is
   signal DecoderInput: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal CurrentDisplay: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
    signal Prescaler: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin

    Multiplex: process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if Prescaler(15) = '0' then
                Prescaler <= Prescaler + 1;
            else
                CurrentDisplay <= CurrentDisplay + 1;
                Prescaler <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process Multiplex;

    SevenSegmentDecoder: entity work.SevenSegment_Decoder(Behavioral)
        generic map ( INVERT_OUTPUT => '1' )
        port map ( number => DecoderInput, segment => SEGMENTS );   

    DecoderInput <= DEC1 when CurrentDisplay = "00" else
                        DEC2 when CurrentDisplay = "01" else
                         DEC3 when CurrentDisplay = "10" else
                         DEC4 when CurrentDisplay = "11";

   ANODES <= "0111" when CurrentDisplay = "00" else
                 "1011" when CurrentDisplay = "01" else
                 "1101" when CurrentDisplay = "10" else
                 "1110" when CurrentDisplay = "11";              

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You don't see digits on a physical display or on your simulated dislay? Did you test the display individually? What is SevenSegment_Decoder?

Comment: Seven Segment Decoder is a component that converts scancodes to g_to_a(SEGMENTS). Actually I am seeing digits on physical display (BASYS2 FPGA) and it is shifting as well, but I can not see them together, the last key I pressed is shown on display. I am thinking I am having a clock issue in the end...

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea of the interface protocol of `SevenSegment_Decoder`, but it does look funny that you only have two inputs, but no clock. How does the decoder know when to interpret the signals?

Comment: 7 segment decoders are usually combinatorial (and-or arrays) or ROMS or LUTS in an FPGA, no need for a clock.

Comment: Decoder is not a source of error, believe me. I resolved some errors though. Now I do see text on 7 segment display, but for example when I press P and O, the text I see is like this: "PPPOO.." I really cant shape how to progress further here. One idea I have in my mind is the if statements in the shifter module. I started to think that they are not suitable for my usage, but couldnt think of a better solution neither ..

Comment: Another important thing to notice about the "wrong" shifting is that it seems like its about clock optimization even though I am also nearly sure all the clocks are suitable for their respective modules. Keyboard Control uses the boards clock, 50 mHz and divides it inside the module to 1/8 of it. Shifter usesthe one that is the clkdivide output, and 7SegmentController uses 2kHz which is enough for us not to differentiate between each display unit

Comment: If you are seeing multiple digits for each button press, are you debouncing the buttons?  Also, if you are running different parts of the circuit off different clocks, you are storing up more problems for yourself. Use a single clock, and add clock enables where you want parts of the circuit to run more slowly.

Comment: I am debouncing in the keyboard interface module yes, when I try it out individually, no matter how long I press, I only get only 1 scancode. As for clocks, I have a divider for shifter module(I have to have one, to adjust the speed of shifting right?), the FPGA(50 MHz) clock directly goes into KeyboardControl as it works fine with that clock individually, and I also direct FPGA's clock to SevenSegmentController (which has a prescaler inside), to be able to show each digit differently.

Comment: Shifter should run off the same clock, using the divided clock as a clock enable.

Comment: I didnt get what you meant, can you please explain it more? How will I use the divided clock as enable and at the same time run with 50MHz clock?

Answer (score 0):

"I haven't thought of any way/method to try out 7 segment controller"

Unless you are using a VERY old version of ISE, certainly older than ISE10, it has a fairly decent simulator (ISIM) built in. (ISIM goes back further than ISE10, but it wasn't really usable and even ISIM 10 had its problems...)

You would save a lot of time if you wrote a simple testbench and unit-tested these modules as you went along.

Comment: I am using ISE 12.4 and am also aware of testbenching, but I tested these modules by hand as I made progress. The reason I didn't spare any time to test Seven Segment Controller is that I used it in another project as well, so I am confident it is not malfunctioning.